# Which positive whole number below 100 has the most number of factors?

Tags: functions

Is there a mathematical function that can be done without a computer that accurately outputs the number of factors a number has, then solve this problem?
Or is there a direct way to do so?

Comment: $2^5 \cdot 3 = 96$ or do repeated factors not count?

Comment: I'd bet on $64$, unless you mean distinct factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295465/how-many-positive-integers-are-factors-of-a-given-number) adresses the question about a mathematical function which outputs the number of factors. The numbers under 100 with most factors are $60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5$, $84=2^2\cdot3\cdot7$, $96=2^5\cdot3$ and $72=2^3\cdot3^2$, which all have 12 factors.

The numbers which have more factors than any smaller number are called highly composite numbers, more info [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html)

Comment: Okay!  
That reall helped!